# crash as a transitive verb

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use crash as a transitive verb ? And is there a less awkward sounding way to say for example; the pilot crashed the airplane ?

Comment: "*The pilot crashed the airplane*" sounds perfectly normal, natural, and idiomatic to me.  I'm not sure there is *any* more common or natural way to put it.  What's bothering you about *crash* as a transitive verb?  All dictionaries include transitive definitions for it. In fact, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crash) even has a specific definition dedicated to aircraft: "***to cause (an aircraft) to hit land or water violently** resulting in severe damage*".

Comment: I offer my apologies to this site's active users. When I posted my question I did not know what is expected of users before they post. However I will say that there are plenty of examples of intransitive verbs being used as transitive verbs,sadly by "language professionals". And so: has the word crash slipped into the language as a transitive verb ? In other words; has it always been a transitive verb ? If not , when did it become one ?

Answer (score 1):

*Crash* is an [ergative verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb), which means it can be both transitive or intransitive. When it's transitive, *airplane* is the direct object: `The pilot crashed the airplane.` When it's intransitive, *airplane* is the subject: `The airplane crashed.`

Wikipedia divides ergative verbs into the following categories:

> - Verbs suggesting a change of state — break, burst, form, heal, melt,
>     tear, transform
> - Verbs of cooking — bake, boil, cook, fry
> - Verbs of movement — move, shake, sweep, turn, walk
> - Verbs involving vehicles — drive, fly, reverse, run, sail

*Crash* would fit into that last category, verbs involving vehicles, so it's correct to use it as both a transitive verb and an intransitive verb.

Comment: It's not safe to assume that all verbs in these semantic classes can be used in both transitive and intransitive constructions. 'The rice microwaved' and 'the car pushed easily' are not idiomatic.

Comment: I never said that all verbs in those categories are ergative, just that verbs that are ergative can be put into those categories.

Comment: In that case, you're using 'so' (= 'therefore') wrongly. It fits into the last category _because_ it is used ergatively and involves using a vehicle.